# Android eclipse create text file in /data/data

Tags: android, eclipse, file

I want to create a text file in /data/data but it doesn't work

```
try{
File myFile = new File("/data/data/x.txt")
myFile.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
myOutWriter.append("test");
myOutWriter.close();
fOut.close();
} [...]
```

Comment: Are you ready for rooting your device for all this?

Comment: And i have already activated the root permission in the manifest, but i don't know how to go on

Answer (score 3):

you can not write in `data/data` because you have not the permission to do it . You can write a file inside `data/data/yourapplication` this way using openFileOutput

```
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(myFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
myOutWriter.append("test");
myOutWriter.close();
```